# Same Function in different ViewController using Swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, generic-programming, generic-type-argument

```
  class FirstViewController : UiViewController {
      example("First Value","Second Value")

      func example(_ firstParameter: String, _ secondParameter: String) {
         var one = self.ValueOne[0].first
         var two = self.ValueTwo[0].second
         var three = ShareClass.Variable.value
         var four = keychain.get('name')
         var five = self.variableNameFive
         var six = firstParameter 
         var seven = secondParameter  
      }
    }
  class SecondViewController : UiViewController {
    example("Random String","Random Value String")

    func example(_ firstParameter: String, _ secondParameter: String) {
       var one = self.ValueOne[0].first
       var two = self.ValueTwo[0].second
       var three = ShareClass.Variable.value
       var four = keychain.get('name')
       var five = self.variableNameFive
       var six = firstParameter 
       var seven = secondParameter  
     }
    }
 class ThirdViewController : UiViewController {
    example("Dynamic String","Dynamic Value Type")

    func example(_ firstParameter: String, _ secondParameter: String) {
       var one = self.ValueOne[0].first
       var two = self.ValueTwo[0].second
       var three = ShareClass.Variable.value
       var four = keychain.get('name')
       var five = self.variableNameFive
       var six = firstParameter 
       var seven = secondParameter  
     }
    }
class FourthViewController : UiViewController {
    example("Complicated String","Complicated String Variable")

    func example(_ firstParameter: String, _ secondParameter: String) {
       var one = self.ValueOne[0].first
       var two = self.ValueTwo[0].second
       var three = ShareClass.Variable.value
       var four = keychain.get('name')
       var five = self.variableNameFive
       var six = firstParameter 
       var seven = secondParameter  
     }
    }
```

In above code I wrote the function which as the variable value from that particular view controller.

As it is the same code repeated in various viewcontroller.
Im trying to write it as a single function `example()` in struct or class file and call it in different viewcontroller.

Old methods follow UIViewController Extension file. Any best way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You should extend your UIViewController class. 
You can call this example method from all of your ViewControllers.

```
extension UIViewController {
func example(_ firstParameter: String, _ secondParameter: String) {
    var one = self.ValueOne[0].first
    var two = self.ValueTwo[0].second
    var three = ShareClass.Variable.value
    var four = keychain.get('name')
    var five = self.variableNameFive
    var six = firstParameter
    var seven = secondParameter
}
```

Or as Vipin said, you can create a custom class.

```
class CustomClass: UIViewController {
    func example(_ firstParameter: String, _ secondParameter: String) {
        var one = self.ValueOne[0].first
        var two = self.ValueTwo[0].second
        var three = ShareClass.Variable.value
        var four = keychain.get('name')
        var five = self.variableNameFive
        var six = firstParameter
        var seven = secondParameter
    }   
}
```

And after this, you can use your ViewControllers like this:

```
class CustomViewController: CustomClass {
   //If you want to add VC specific actions to this method, you can override it
    override func example(_ firstParameter: String, _ secondParameter: String) {
        super.example(firstParameter, secondParameter)
        print("something more just for this VC")
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        example("First Param", "Second param")
    }
}
```

Comment: you can create a base class and then intermitted to all class so you can easily use and only write that code in one class means base class